# Android Studio, Databasehelper Class not working for some reason

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Alright, So. I've been trying for the last couple of hours to display a database on a list view widget in android studio. I used this exact code in another project and it worked find, but now that I am trying to integrate it into this one, the app continuously crashes when ever I try to pull from the database. this includes the getLight Method and the getAllLight Method. I am at a complete lost here. Again, this code worked, idk why i am getting an error now. is there something wrong with my methods? is there something I can try?

```
package com.studios.primitive.safealwayz.ui.main.Light;
import com.studios.primitive.safealwayz.ui.main.Account.AccountModel;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LightDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String LIGHTS = "LIGHTS";
    public static final String COLUMN_LIGHTID = "LIGHTID";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "USERNAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_LOCATION = "LOCATION";
    public static final String COLUMN_STATUS = "STATUS";

    public LightDatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, "lights.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTableStatement = "CREATE TABLE " + LIGHTS + " (" + COLUMN_LIGHTID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_LOCATION + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_STATUS + " BOOL)";
        db.execSQL(createTableStatement);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public boolean addLight(LightModel light, AccountModel accountModel) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, accountModel.getUserName());
        cv.put(COLUMN_LOCATION, light.getLocation());
        cv.put(COLUMN_STATUS, light.isActive());
        long insert = db.insert(LIGHTS, null, cv);
        return insert != -1;

    }
    public void changeLightStatus(LightModel light){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_LIGHTID, light.getLightID());
        cv.put(COLUMN_LOCATION,light.getLocation());
        cv.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, light.getUsername());
        cv.put(COLUMN_STATUS, light.isActive());
        db.update(LIGHTS, cv, COLUMN_LIGHTID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(light.getLightID())});


    }
    public List<LightModel> getAllLights(AccountModel account){
        List<LightModel> rtnList = new ArrayList<>();
        String queryCommand = "SELECT * FROM " + LIGHTS +" WHERE " + COLUMN_USERNAME + " = " + "'"+account.getUserName()+"'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryCommand,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int LightID = cursor.getInt(0);
                String username = cursor.getString(1);
                String lightLocation = cursor.getString(2);
                boolean lightStatus = cursor.getInt(3) == 1;
                LightModel newLight = new LightModel(lightLocation, account);
                newLight.setActive(lightStatus);
                newLight.setLightID(LightID);

                rtnList.add(newLight);

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }else{
            //returns an empty list
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return rtnList;
    }
    public LightModel getLight(String id, String user){
        LightModel light = new LightModel(user);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String queryCommand = "SELECT * FROM " + LIGHTS + " WHERE "+ COLUMN_LIGHTID + " = "+ "'" + id +"'";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryCommand,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int LightID = cursor.getInt(0);
                String username = cursor.getString(1);
                String location = cursor.getString(2);
                boolean status = cursor.getInt(3) == 1? true: false;

                light.setLightID(LightID);
                light.setUsername(username);
                light.setLocation(location);
                light.setActive(status);

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }else{
            //returns an empty list
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return light;

    }
}
```

Here is the Activity Class

```
package com.studios.primitive.safealwayz;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.studios.primitive.safealwayz.ui.main.Account.AccountModel;
import com.studios.primitive.safealwayz.ui.main.Light.LightDatabaseHelper;
import com.studios.primitive.safealwayz.ui.main.Light.LightModel;

import java.util.List;

public class AccountLightActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button turn;
    ListView listV;
    EditText lightID;
    ArrayAdapter<LightModel> lightArrayAdapter;
    LightDatabaseHelper lightDatabaseHelper;






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_light);
        final AccountModel model = (AccountModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("obj");
        turn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.turn_light);
        listV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        lightID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.light_id_input);

        /*
        lightArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<LightModel>(AccountLightActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lightDatabaseHelper.getAllLights(model));
        listV.setAdapter(lightArrayAdapter);

         */

        turn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String lightInput = lightID.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(AccountLightActivity.this, model.getUserName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                LightModel li = lightDatabaseHelper.getLight(lightInput, model.getUserName());
                Toast.makeText(AccountLightActivity.this, li.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                /*

                if (lightInput.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(AccountLightActivity.this, "Please Choose a LightID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    LightModel li = lightDatabaseHelper.getLight(lightInput, model.getUserName());
                    if(li.isActive()){
                        li.setActive(false);
                    }else{
                        li.setActive(true);
                    }
                    lightDatabaseHelper.changeLightStatus(li);
                    Toast.makeText(AccountLightActivity.this, li.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    lightArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<LightModel>(AccountLightActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lightDatabaseHelper.getAllLights(model));
                    listV.setAdapter(lightArrayAdapter);
                }

                 */
            }
        });



    }
}
```

and finally, here is the error I've been getting.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.studios.primitive.safealwayz, PID: 2269
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.studios.primitive.safealwayz.AccountLightActivity$1.onClick(AccountLightActivity.java:53)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you addLight() first? Maybe your db is empty.

Comment: Yes, the database has light entries.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryCommand,null); and check if the variable holds any data when executing. You have to use the debugger.